# Correlated categorical predictors in logistic regression

Tags: r, correlation, categorical-data, predictive-models, modeling

Suppose I have three categorical variables, x, y, and z and I have a binary response variable r. I want to predict the response using the glm model.

Should I check the association between x, y, and z with chisq.test? What if all of them are significantly correlated? I can't do the prediction?

Comment: just use: glm(r ~ x + y + z, family = binomial)

Comment: @AminShn I don't need to be worry about their correlation?

Comment: You are not dealing with numerical variables so no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correlation/association among the categorical predictors is not by itself a problem, unless it is severe. So just fit your logistic regression, and only think about problems if they occur then.

For further advice we would need more information.